# Error trying to use rand from std library cstdlib with g++

Tags: g++

I was trying to use the random function in Ubuntu compiling with g++ on a larger program and for some reason rand just gave weird compile errors. For testing purposes I made the simplest program I could and it still gives errors.

**Program:**

---

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  cout << "Random number " << rand();

return 0;
}
```

### **Error when compiling with the terminal**

```
sudo g++ chapter_3/tester.cpp ./test
./test: In function `_start':
/build/buildd/eglibc-2.10.1/csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf/start.S:65: multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.10.1/csu/../sysdeps/i386/elf /start.S:65: first defined here
./test:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_fp_hw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
./test: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
./test:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
./test: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
./test: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x4): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
./test: In function `main':
(.text+0xb4): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/cceF0x0p.o:tester.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
./test: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple definition of `__DTOR_END__'
./test:(.dtors+0x4): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in ./test(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be linking the file to itself, resulting in multiple definitions of symbols in the resulting executable. Try this instead:

```
g++ chapter_3/tester.cpp
```

Also don't use sudo for a command such as this.

Comment: Or use the `-o` flag to `g++`: `g++ chapter_3/tester.cpp -o ./test`